# Same Formulae Different Values in Different File- Problem of round off of decimal

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

Problem in 1 File, I have divided and later multiplied same result with the denominator and it gives different numberator.
[image: I have divided and later multiplied same result with the denominator and it gives different numberator]

But in another file it is ok:
[image]

Comment: maybe the calcs are set to manual on the first and you need to press F9 to calculate?

Comment: Calucation is automatic, doing f9 also does not help.

Comment: just double check that there really is no number in C5.

Comment: If i increase the precision of decimal to 10 difference becomes nil in the first file. But in second file it is ok with 2 precision

Comment: I have found the solution, It has to do with the excel setting, Change the following settings:

File > Options > Advanced > Untick the **Set Precision as Displayed**

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the excel setting, Change the following settings:

File > Options > Advanced > Untick the **Set Precision as Displayed**